# Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting an error in IE9 at the line jQuery( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" ); . 
It says Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

    jQuery("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                window.location.href = '/gra/logout';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have included the js files related to jquery like this:

```
  <link type="text/css"   href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}"  rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'jquery.treeview.css')}"  />
    <script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery.treeview.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery.treeview.edit.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery.treeview.async.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know it depends on the order of includes but want to make sure am I missing a library?

Comment: After 36 other questions asked, one would expect you'd learn how to format and indent code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from above you included just jQuery, and jQueryui css but not the jQuery UI js files. (unless jQuery tools includes it)